# I couldn't pass parameters dynamically to html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When i pass parameters in onclick function it doesn't appear but if remove parameters, it works perfectly. please help.
thanks

```
x.innerHTML='<div class="item txt1" onclick="map(\''+lat, lng+'\');"></div><br/>';
```

Comment: `x.innerHTML = '<div class="item txt1" onclick="map(\'' + lat + '\',\'' + lng + '\');"></div><br/>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 parameters so both should be concatenated to a string string like below

```
x.innerHTML = '<div class="item txt1" onclick="map(\'' + lat + '\',\'' + lng + '\');"></div><br/>';
```

But if both `lat` and `lng` are numerical values then

```
x.innerHTML = '<div class="item txt1" onclick="map(' + lat + ',' + lng + ');"></div><br/>';
```